# Online service or Linux-based tool that provides iOS malware analysis?

Tags: linux, ios, iphone-app, malware

Is there any iOS online analysis tool?

The only thing I have seen so far is [VirusTotal](https://www.virustotal.com/). Are there other tools that can provide online reports?

My main issue is that I do not have any Apple hardware right now, so I can not use desktop-based tools or run an app on an iPhone.

I use Ubuntu, so I need some web service or a Linux-based tool that can give me insight into app functionality and a verdict about its maliciousness.

Answer (score 2):

There is a Chinese online application security scanner (VisualThreat: Mobile Application Security Credit Evaluation System) at http://www.visualthreat.com/index.action

The followings are the main features of the service (in machine translated):

- comprehensive safety analysis program: static behavior, dynamic
  behavior, malicious behavior characteristic resolve family related
  and inter-family resolve
- measurable (0-100) to assess the credibility of mobile application
  security system
- comprehensive application of risk analysis matrix, including but not
  limited to loss of privacy, SMS monitoring, behavior monitoring.
- Automatic mobile application security vulnerability scanning accurate
  malicious behavior and advanced persistent threat of attack detection
- real-time mobile applications industry's most authoritative safety
  analysis report

Comment: Thanks for the response. The link you have shared seems quite helpful, but it requires iTunes url, while I have bunch of IPA files from random sources. Some of these IPA might not even be on itunes, do you happen to know service that lets user upload app?

Comment: Hello Gürol'Ca, could you please describe in details how your solution targets iOS in particular? Thanks!

Comment: As @blackfyre says the online service scans iOS apps by providing their iTunes URL (e.g. https://itunes.apple.com/app/id#########). The report is not as informational as in Android.

Comment: In static analysis scope:
The reports list the following information:
- The 'risky' actions (Phone Call, Keyboard cache, InApp Purchasing, Audio input/record, Location Tracking, Camera, Photo Gallery, WiFi connection, Address Book, Email account, Mobile Safari Setting and history, Youtube application, Ads Networks, Accelerometer, Calendar)

Comment: - The screenshot and artwork URLs (shown in iTunes)
- The developer's URL (shown in iTunes)
- Features (iosUniversal??)
- Supported Devices (shown in iTunes)
- Content Rating (shown in iTunes)
- Supported languages (shown in iTunes)
- Genres (shown in iTunes)
- Description (shown in iTunes)
- Minimum OS version
- User rating and average rating (shown in iTunes)
 (shown in iTunes)

Comment: In dynamic analysis scope:
The reports list counts and percentage of App behaviors (read, write, http, socket, crypt, log, and key chain) and the crynological dump of these behaviours with time information and their parameters (which can be purchased)